# How do I install VMware Workstation Player 12.11 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-player

When I attempted to install [VMware Workstation Player 12.11](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0) on Ubuntu 16.04, I got the following error:

```
root@workstation:/home/user/Downloads# ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@workstation:/home/user/Downloads#
```

Answer (score 7):

*Make sure you `sudo` all these commands, or run these as root.*

The missing module is in the file `libcanberra-gtk-module.so`. It's included in the package `libcanberra-gtk-module` ([source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcanberra-gtk-module.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=amd64)).

So you'll need to:

1. Install `libcanberra-gtk-module`:

   ```
   sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
   ```
2. Create a symlink to the missing library:

   ```sh
   sudo ln -sT "../$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so" /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
   ```
3. Make the `.bundle` file you downloaded from VMware executable and run it:

   ```
   chmod +x ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
   sudo ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
   ```
4. Follow the GUI installation that pops up on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

You can forgo the need for GTK modules if you use the command-line installer instead:

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle --console
```